# Invalid preprocessing directive mingw

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, mingw, codeblocks

I downloaded Microsoft DirectX SDK and tried to open the sample BasicHLSL in Code::Blocks using MingW, after changing the file encoding to unicode and trying to compile I get an extremely large number (500+) of warnings all saying "null character(s) ignored [enabled by default]" and multiple errors all saying "invalid preprocessing directive" followed by # then a letter.

The really strange thing is that the error doesn't seem to match the line of code, for example here is one error

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\DXUT\Core\DXUT.h Line 15 error: invalid preprocessing directive #d
```

And now here are lines 14-16 from DXUT.h

14 `#include "dxsdkver.h"`

15 `#if ( _DXSDK_PRODUCT_MAJOR < 9 || _DXSDK_BUILD_MAJOR < 1949 )`

16 `#error The installed DXSDK is out of date.`

Here is another error

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Samples\C++\DXUT\Core\DXUT.h Line 133 error: invalid preprocessing directive #i
```

and here's line 132-134 fomr DXUT.h

132 `D3DDEVTYPE DeviceType;`

133 `D3DFORMAT AdapterFormat;`

134 `DWORD BehaviorFlags;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you changed the file encoding I believe you changed it to "wide characters" (UTF-16). This creates a 16 bit value for each character. The first of character of a wide character representation of most US-ASCII is zero. This would explain why you got a lot of 'zeros in your source code' errors. The compiler expects 8 bit characters.

Comment: I just tried encoding with every format available including UTF-8, so I don't think thats the problem.

Comment: If you open dxsdkver.h does it #define _DXSDK_PRODUCT_MAJOR?  There might be a conditional within that include file that causes it not to define it. Then the #if in the dxut.h will fail

Comment: I don't think that will work based on the other error I linked but I'll try it.

Comment: The error indicates it the preprocessor directive. The preprocessor directive there is the '#if'. If the value it's testing is not set that would cause an error. This is commonly caused by compile time options that are usually set in the IDE project not in the source code. Since you're using mingw instead of msvc it seems a reasonable suspicion to me. You might also have an issue with text encoding as I mentioned. Open your file in a binary editor and see.